# Laravel "Specified key was too long" when creating notifications table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravels' default migration to create a notifications table.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->morphs('notifiable');
        $table->text('data');
        $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

But I get an error when trying to use it:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `notifications` add index `n
  otifications_notifiable_id_notifiable_type_index`(`notifiable_id`, `notifiable_type`))



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

**Update**

I changed the name of the index column to notifiable_index, but it still complaints about the length of the index key.

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `notifications` add index `n
  otifiable_index`(`notifiable_id`, `notifiable_type`))



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

Comment: What is the collation of the `notifiable` columns?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @PhilippSander had to use another methods to create a shorter key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using [Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#creating-indexes) and running a version of MySQL older than the 5.7.7 release. You may solve this by calling the `Schema::defaultStringLength` method within your `AppServiceProvider` class's `boot` method.

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: I have Laravel 5.3

Comment: @naneri did you give it a try?

Comment: @PhilippSander Yah. I tried for mariadb 10.1 and worked fine.

Comment: @naneri then please share it with us!

Comment: @PhilippSander posted an answer below.

Comment: It doesn't work in Laravel 5.4.21. You should use `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder::$defaultStringLength = 191` instead.

Comment: Works with Laravel 5.8. I had to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing is I just created a manual index for the notifiable id. Here is the migration:

```
    Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->text('data');
        $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unsignedInteger("notifiable_id");
        $table->string("notifiable_type");
        $table->index('notifiable_id');
    });
```

Instead of having the command:

```
 $table->morphs('notifiable');
```

I have 3 lines:

```
    $table->unsignedInteger("notifiable_id");
    $table->string("notifiable_type");
    $table->index('notifiable_id');
```

The downside is that the index is not combined based on type+id, it is only based on id. But because I only have User model that can be notified, that is ok for me.

Comment: this is a better answer

Answer (score -1):

Laravel uses conventions for the foreign keys based on what your tables and names are. But you can supply your own name for the key:

```
$table->morphs('notifiable', 'mykeyname');
```

That way, you can ensure that the key name is short enough.

Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L963

Comment: I updated the column name, but it still complaints about the key length :(. You can see the update in the first post.